# Symfony2 - Catchable Fatal Error - Fixtures

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to load some fixtures in my database and I am going to become crazy due to doctrine error. This is it:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorExce ption]  Catchable
>   Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   TuzonaBundle\Entity\Ciudades::setProvincias() must be an instance of
>   TuzonaBundle\Entity\Provincias, string given, called in
>   /httpdocs/src/TuzonaBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/Ciudad.php on line 141 and
>   defined

As you can see, the problem is specific enough. The problem is that I am not given to 'setProvincias()' the right datatype. I guess the right datatype is an integer, but it doesn't work like that... I tried with a string, with the same result.

The code is as follow

TuzonaBundle\Entity\Ciudades.php

```
class Ciudades
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provincias", inversedBy="ciudades")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_provincia", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $provincias;

    /**
    * Set provincias
    *
    * @param \TuzonaBundle\Entity\Provincias $provincias
    * @return Ciudades
    */
    public function setProvincias(\TuzonaBundle\Entity\Provincias $provincias = null)
    {
    $this->provincias = $provincias;

    return $this;
    }

}
```

TuzonaBundle\Entity\Provincias

```
class Provincias
{

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ciudades", mappedBy="provincias")
    */
    protected $ciudades;

    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the key of problem is about your words:

> I guess the right datatype is an integer, but it doesn't work like
>   that... I tried with a string, with the same result

No, it is not integer.

You should to call "setProvincias" with an object of Provincias datatype. 
So if you are loads data via fixtures, you should to create some Provincias fixtures, like

ProvinciasData.php

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $province = new \YourApp\TuzonaBundle\Entity\Provincias();
        $this->addReference('YourApp\TuzonaBundle\Entity\Provincias-1', $province);
        $manager->persist($province);
        $manager->flush();
}
```

CiudadesData.php

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $ciudade = new \YourApp\TuzonaBundle\Entity\Ciudades();
        $ciudade->setProvincias($this->getReference('YourApp\TuzonaBundle\Entity\Provincias-1'));
        $manager->persist($ciudade);

        $manager->flush();
}
```